# Compare every 1kb of contents of two files instead of character by character

Tags: c

I'm having this function that compares characters from 2 files, and displays the errors found (line + position).

```
 void compareFiles(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2) 
 { 
    char ch1 = getc(fp1); 
    char ch2 = getc(fp2); 
    int error = 0, pos = 0, line = 1; 

    while (ch1 != EOF && ch2 != EOF) 
    { 
        pos++; 

        if (ch1 == '\n' && ch2 == '\n') 
        { 
            line++; 
            pos = 0; 
        } 

        if (ch1 != ch2) 
        { 
            error++; 
            printf("Line Number : %d \tError"
               " Position : %d \n", line, pos); 
        } 

        ch1 = getc(fp1); 
        ch2 = getc(fp2); 
    } 

    printf("Total Errors : %d\t", error);
```

But I would like to take every 1kb of data and compare it to another one from file2, because then I want to see how many such blocks are identical. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you still want to know the position (line/pos) of the mismatch? If you read and compare in chunks you will lose any line information.

Comment: nope, I don't need those anymore. I'll only verify how many 1kb blocks are identical. That after I'll see how to use fread

Comment: You could just rename `line` to `block` and modify the `pos` logic. What are you trying to achive by comparing blocks?

Comment: Side note: in your current code, `ch1` and `ch2` need to be ints, not chars.

Answer (score 3):

Read in chunks, so `fread` not `getc`.

Then compare in chunks, so `strcmp` (or `memcmp`) not char `==`.

Don't forget that your inputs may have different lengths (which `fread` will tell you), so I suggest null-terminating both buffers after your `fread`, or better yet fail early if the lengths differ.